# Exists a possibility to let Google Data Studio process an integer year as year-end-date

Tags: google-bigquery, looker-studio

In my table there is only a year column as integer.

In Google Data Studio it is possible to convert this to date.year `YYYY`, but it is not possible to use this column in a date calculation.

What would be nice is that Data Studio date.year `YYYY` could process like `YYYYmmdd`.

Maybe it is already possible, but I could not find.

Answer (score 0):

Data studio allows your to write a query to BigQuery as input source, you can use a query like this:

```sql
with yourTable as (select 2020 as year_column)
select *, DATE(year_column, 12, 31) as year_end_date
from yourTable;
```

or, if a lot of places need the same transformation, you can define a view for this

```sql
CREATE VIEW yourView 
AS SELECT *, DATE(year_column, 12, 31) as year_end_date
from yourTable;
```

Answer (score 0):

**1) Date_Field**
- A YYYYMMDD Date field could be created at the Data Source by using the [`CONCAT`](https://support.google.com/datastudio/answer/7583443) function to add Month and  Day components (Dec 31st in the [Calculated Field](https://support.google.com/datastudio/answer/6299685) below); since the format would be YYYYMMDD, the field will automatically be recognised as a Date field, however, as best practice, added the [`TODATE`](https://support.google.com/datastudio/answer/7037300) function:

```
TODATE(CONCAT(Year, "12", "31"), "%Y%m%d", "%Y%m%d")
```

GIF to elaborate on #1:

[image]

**2) (Optional) [Date Range Control](https://support.google.com/datastudio/answer/6291067)**
- Set a [Date Range](https://support.google.com/datastudio/answer/9272806), for example `This year`.

**3) (Optional) [Time Series](https://support.google.com/datastudio/answer/7059697) Chart**
- ***Dimension***: `Date_Field` (Granularity: Year).
- [***Comparison Date Range***](https://support.google.com/datastudio/answer/9272806): `Previous period`.
- ***Style***: Bars

[Google Data Studio Report](https://datastudio.google.com/reporting/207e634f-b5a3-4f0c-8091-75d3eb2a5f18) and GIF to demonstrate #2 & #3:

[image]